# Check ios versions then call functions of uiviewcontroller accordingly

Tags: ios, ios7, ios6, ios8

I was stuck with an orientation issue in iPad for all versions. My app is designed in such a way that it supports from ios 6 till ios 8.

According to apple since **willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:** is DEPRECATED from ios8, i used  **viewWillTransitionToSize:**  for ios8.

When hit with issue, my first solution was providing macros to decide the version as either ios 8 or below and perform the functions accordingly.

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
// Works on >= version 8.0
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
    // my code go here for ios 8
}
#else
// Works on < version 8.0
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    // my code go here when version is below 8.0
}
#endif
```

I also checked and run it.. I received the output as expected.

But it was said that the code was wrong.. as  **i am trying to turn version checking into a compile-time decision. The version checking must be a  RUNTIME decision. both the ios7 and ios8 code must BOTH be compiled into the executable.**

So changed the function as below without any version check:

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];


    // my code go here without any version check

}
```

I'm hardly unable to understand the line  ***"both the ios7 and ios8 code must BOTH be compiled into the executable."*** - what this really mean.

Wish to know why i shouldn't provide compile-time decision?

Also if i want to do it... without using notification.. is there any way through which i can able to handle by calling these functions at runtime with version check?

Kindly let me have the comments on this.

Comment: You seem to be confused between compile-time platform checking and runtime checking.

Comment: @Droppy, i wish to know more about compile-time checking and runtime checking.

Comment: Well bottom line is that the same binary will run under all supported iOS versions, so you cannot exclude methods at compile time.  Not to mention there is no such thing as knowing what version you are running on at compile time (just saying it out loud tells you it's wrong).  There is the concept of compiling for a specific version of iOS, however that will always be >= minimum targeted version.  Getting this right at runtime is non-trivial.